# Eiffel: How do I compare the type of an object to a given type?

Tags: eiffel

How do I compare the type of an object to a given type (instanceOf statement in Java)?

```
do_stuff (a_type: TYPE)
    local
        an_object: ANY
    do
        an_object := get_from_sky
        if an_object.instanceOf (a_type) then
            io.putstring("Object is same type as parameter")
        else
            io.putstring("Object is NOT same type as parameter")
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the generality of the solution, there are different options. First, consider the case when `an_object` is always attached:

1. `a_type` always denotes a reference type.

   For reference types one can use the feature `attempted` (with an alias `/`) of the class `TYPE`.

   ```
   if attached (a_type / an_object) then
       -- Conforms.
   else
       -- Does not conform.
   end
   ```
2. `a_type` can denote either a reference or expanded type.

   The feature `attempted` of the class `TYPE` is unusable in this case because it would always return an attached object for expanded types. Therefore, the types should be compared directly.

   ```
   if an_object.generating_type.conforms_to
       (({REFLECTOR}.type_of_type ({REFLECTOR}.detachable_type (a_type.type_id))))
   then
       -- Conforms.
   else
       -- Does not conform.
   end
   ```

If `an_object` could also be `Void`, the condition should have additional tests for voidness. Denoting the conditions from the cases above with `C`, the tests that handle detachable `an_object` would be:

```
if
        -- If an_object is attached.
    attached an_object and then C or else
        -- If an_object is Void.
    not attached an_object and then not a_type.is_attached
then
    -- Conforms.
else
    -- Does not conform.
end
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check if the type of `a_type` is identical to the type of `an_object`,
use the feature `{ANY}.same_type`, if you want to check type conformance just use `{ANY}.conforms_to`

```
do_stuff (a_type: TYPE)
    local
        an_object: ANY
    do
        an_object := get_from_sky
        if an_object.same_type (a_type) then
             io.putstring("Object an_object is same type as argment a_type")
        elseif an_object.conforms_to (a_type)
             io.putstring("Object an_object conforms to type of a_type ")
        else
             io.putstring ("...")  
        end
    end
```

Comment: The features `same_type` and `conforms_to` expect an object as an argument, not a type. In other words, they compare types of two objects, not a type of an object against some other type. For example, `("").same_type ({STRING})` gives `False`, and `("").same_type ("")` gives `True`. In the original question, only an object and a type are given, not two objects.